# Console log read data property

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm tring use console log to checks some object in my js project. In

```
scope.files;
```

I have written a data about file.

Output from

```
console.log(scope.files);
```

is:
[image]

How could I read a name from that object?

`var name = scope.file.File.name;`

That dosen't work.

I'd like also to write id on the same level as is written name in that way:

```
var file_id = data.success;
scope.files.id = file_id;
```

Sorry if my question is very easy, but I'm beginner ;)

I would be greatful for help ;)

Comment: That little blue `i` is suspect - it will say something like "this is the current view of the object, not what it was when it was logged" - is any of your code async?  As well as the array issue, you might be trying to get hold of it before it's present.

Answer (score 2):

`scope.file` is an array of objects (inheriting from *File*).

```
0: File 
  ...
1:File
```

in the log means that theres a File at index 0.
So to access it you have to pass the index:

```
console.log(scope.file[0].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scope.files` is an array, so if you want to access the name of one of the files, you have to index it first:

```
console.log(scope.files[0].name);
```

If you have multiple files, you could also use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get all file names into another array:

```
console.log(scope.files.map(x => x.name));
```

---

Similarly, to write to a property, you also have to index the correct file, e.g.:

```
scope.files[0].id = file_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
var name = scope.files[0].name;
```

to store it in a variable or you can also console.log it

```
cosnole.log(scope.files[0].name);
```